# Unable to find an entry point named 'FreeImage_GetFileTypeU' in DLL 'FreeImageNET'

Tags: c#, dllimport, freeimage

I just downloaded FreeImage 3.15.4 Win32 and I'm trying to go through their C# samples.  I have a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio Express 2010, so I recompiled the samples to 64 bit as described here (http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/05/freeimage-and-x64-projects-yes-you-can/).  I also had to change the name of the "FreeImageLibrary" string in FreeImageStaticImports.cs in order to get the sample applications to start (the produced DLL was named FreeImageNet and not FreeImage as the samples expected).

However when I run the samples, I get an "Unable to find an entry point named 'FreeImage_GetFileTypeU' in DLL 'FreeImageNET'." error whenever I call a FreeImage function.  The samples reference the library that contains the DLLImport statements, so I'm not really sure what's broken here.  Does anyone have experience with FreeImage and C# that could offer some advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also had to change the name of the "FreeImageLibrary" string

That's how you got into this trouble.  There are **two** DLLs involved here.  FreeImage.dll is the *native* DLL, it contains the FreeImage_GetFileTypeU export.  FreeImageNET.dll is the *managed* class library that contains the wrappers for the native DLL, it doesn't have that export as the exception message told you.

What you should have done was rebuild the native DLL from source so that you got the 64-bit version of FreeImage.dll.  That blog post told you how to do that.  And offered a download, ymmv.

It must also be copied into the build output folder so that it can be found at runtime.  An easy way to do that is to add it to your project with Project + Add Existing Item and set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer".

Comment: I clearly didn't know what I was doing.  I actually converted the sample projects to x64, not the native FreeImage DLL.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to rebuild that DLL following the very directions I linked to.  None of the solutions convert with Visual Studio Express 2010.  I tried using the offered download, but that doesn't appear to work.  Thanks to your help I am getting the DLLs in the correct locations, I just can't get them to work.  :(

Comment: Don't try this with Express.  Just change the target platform of your C# project to x86 so you can use the regular distribution.  That's hard to do with the Express edition as well, you have to edit the project file with a text editor.  Change "AnyCPU" to "x86".  Free software is only free if your time is free.

Comment: Based on your advice, I went back to the 32-bit libraries and was able to get the examples working.  Turns out FreeImage doesn't appear to do exactly what I wanted anyway, but at least I learned something in the process.  Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm on Linux (Mono, which is supposedly supported) and without changing the `FreeImageLibrary` string to lowercase, it would not find the library, as the filesystem is case-sensitive. Furthermore, when the library finally links, everything seems to work except the library seems to reject everything, none of the samples work (they don't crash, the library just returns errors all the time), etc... I would have expected better support for `FreeImage.NET` but is it stupidly hard to set up.